# My dog and my cats have fleas, and I'm getting bites, is there an infestation?

Tags: cats, dogs, fleas

Both my Border Collie dog and my 2 cats are getting fleas, we noticed from the immense itching. I also started getting many bug bites (I counted around 20 or more) like mosquito bites, but not like ants.

So I was wondering, do the fleas also bite people? If so, how do I get rid of them?

I've been using Raid spray in my room and kept my pets out to make sure they don't get sick, and the bites have decreased, but they still occur, I also washed my bedding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fleas are parasites of mammals and birds. Fleas live by consuming blood or hematophagy, from their hosts.
So they can bite.
To avoid their biting first of all control their origin.
In your case their origin is your pets. So first of all control fleas infestation in them.
To control, the most effective drug used now a days is frontline for dogs and bravecto. These are available in solution form for topical use.
Also wash their bedding.
Although Raid is an insecticide but that is not useful for this situation.

Reference:
Veterinary medicine written by D.C. Blood.

Comment: i just want to add this,bird fleas can bite pets and people but they can not survive and multiply on people and pets.for effective treatment of fleas all people and pets must be treated at the same time,the remedies you mention is effective but you need to give this treatment twice to get rid of the problem(follow the instructions on the package)

Comment: Another addition: Put **all** the beddings of your pets and your own, including your pillows into big garbage bags and seal them as best as you can so no fleas can escape. Then either wash them at at least 60°C / 140°F (without the bags of course) or put them into the freezer for 2 weeks to kill the fleas inside. For more advice about how to battle fleas, have a look at [this related question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/20963/12501).